# How can we give explicit test data and train data to SVM instead of using train_test_split function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm planning to provide the test and train datasets explicitly to the algorithm and not to use the train_test_split method for random splitting of the data into test and train respectively.

And I want to keep the reviews and labels data in the same file while testing as well as training the model.

Can anyone of you please suggest me regarding the same ...

## My code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

with open("/Users/xyz/Desktop/reviews.txt") as f:
    reviews = f.read().split("\n")
with open("/Users/xyz/Desktop/labels.txt") as f:
    labels = f.read().split("\n")

reviews_tokens = [review.split() for review in reviews]


onehot_enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
onehot_enc.fit(reviews_tokens)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reviews_tokens, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=None)

lsvm = LinearSVC()
lsvm.fit(onehot_enc.transform(X_train), y_train)
accuracy_score = lsvm.score(onehot_enc.transform(X_test), y_test)

print("Accuracy score of SVM:" , accuracy_score)
```

## Test.txt

```
review,label
Colors & clarity is superb,positive
Sadly the picture is not nearly as clear or bright as my 40 inch Samsung,negative
```

## Train.txt:

```
review,label
The picture is clear and beautiful,positive
Picture is not clear,negative
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do what you want. The solution is pretty easy:

```
X_train = reviews_tokens[:number_of_rows_of_train_data]
X_test = reviews_tokens[number_of_rows_of_train_data:]
```

Do the same for `y_train` and `y_test`.

Of course you need to know which rows in your file are for training and which are for testing.

If you want to keep features and labels in the same file - no problem with that. You will need one additional step to separate labels from features. It would be a lot easier with pandas.

EDIT

Having the files you provided you can get what you want like this:

```
def load_data(filename):

    X = list()
    y = list()
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            y.append(line[1])
            X.append(line[0].split())

    return X, y

X_train, y_train = load_data('train.txt')
X_test, y_test = load_data('test.txt')
```

Comment: Actually, my training data is amazon dataset and my test data is different. It is not the amazon data. So, I have to give two separate files for testing and training. How can we do that ?

Comment: @Inevitable Step by step. 1 - Load training dataset. 2 - Train. 3 - Load test dataset. 4 - Test. You have already done all these steps with your code, just modify it lil bit according to your needs.

Comment: Actually, here I have used one dataset out of which I have split the data into test and tain respectively.This requirement is different. But in one of my other requirements I have two datasets one should be dedicated for test data and the other for training data

Comment: @Inevitable There is no actual difference between these variants. It is just a matter of how you store your data. Not how you use it. Can you provide links to your datasets or examples of them (couple rows)?

Comment: Hi @Poolka, please find the edited test.txt and train.txt files

Comment: @Inevitable I edited my answer and included a piece of code. You can use it without any changes to get what you want. This is the very basics of data preparation for machine learning so such problems must not be problems at all.